# ¿Como hacer que funcione el scrolling de mi pagina web en Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Saludos, mi problema es el siguiente tengo un sitio web alojado en Wordpress y siempre ha funcionado sin problemas hasta hoy, por alguna razón en el navegador Google Chrome no funciona el scrolling con la rueda del mouse, pero en otros navegadores si funciona a la perfección. Si alguien tiene alguna idea de cual puede ser la causa de esto.

PD: ya revise el CSS y JavaScript, esta es la pagina [website](http://www.macroplus.web.ve)

Comment: Hola Brian, bienvenido al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! para que obtengas buenas respuestas te sugiero leer el documento [ask], saludos!

Comment: Sería que revisases esto: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/theme-wont-scroll-in-chrome-on-mac/, esto: https://www.webempresa.com/foro/4-Preguntas-Sobre-Joomla/156415-No-me-funciona-la-rueda-de-scroll-del-rat%C3%B3n-en-httpswwwmeditacionmusicacom.html y esto: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome-es/5hOkN-WibqY;context-place=forum/chrome-es

Comment: Tu problema tiene que ver con el mapa que incluiste en el pie de tu página, ya que este mismo mapa tiene un script que hace tenga un efecto Parallax y eso afecte en unas versiones de google Chrome. Saludos.

Comment: Ya revise el plugin que ejecutaba el mapa de Google y aun des habilitando el efecto parallax sigue sin funcionar el scrolling.

Comment: Con deshabilitar el plugin jQuery Updater ya debería volver a funcionar correctamente. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes eliminar la referencia en JavaScript a **Smooth Scrolling** ya que Google Chrome hace conflicto con algunos *themes* de Wordpress. Prueba con eso.

Comment: Gracias de verdad, me soluciono el problema que presentaba en la pagina. Saludos.